# New iTerm2 Window Here option open two tabs

Tags: terminal, iterm

When I right-clicked a folder and choose the services -> New iTerm2 Window Here option in the menu, I am getting two iTerm2 windows like this.

[image]

But I don't need that root level terminal here (The right side terminal of the image), because I only need this folder path terminal only. How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: When you open iTerm2 from Applications, have you 2 windows or only one?

Comment: Do you want it gone? Canonical ⌘ + W to close active window.

Comment: What version iTerm 2 are you using? It sounds like you may have more than one Profile being loaded. You can check the profiles in the menubar under `Profiles`

Comment: @Jean_JD Only one.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Can we turn off that appearing? Close it all the time, waste the time :(

Comment: @akostar I am using a profile named "default" profile. the command is loggin shell

Comment: This happens when I try to open Item2 on folder right-click the folder and when I choosing the iTerm2 Window Here option

Comment: At first glance and based on my understanding of circumstances isin’t it expected behavior? You give command for a new window and you get new window in addition to existing one?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg yes you got it right. I want only one window for that current folder, but with that, it is opening a new blank window with a root-level path. It is unexpected for me. Why it is opening that right side window with the root-level path in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is open issue [iterm2 opens two window or two tabs when launched from services](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/6562) where possible workarounds are described (also root cause of the problem as well).

From productivity point (if you end in shell anyway) you could consider switching to console based file manager (like [vifm](https://vifm.info), [ranger](https://ranger.github.io), [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn), [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org) etc). You will get productivity boost from relying on keyboard only. There is also command-line fuzzy-finder [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) which could be handy.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution that works, I left **iTerm2 Settings > General > Startup** as **Use System Window Restoration Setting** and also left **Advanced > Enable session restoration** on. I changed the setting under **Advanced > Open a window at startup?** to **No.** Now everything works as you would expect, I startup iTerm2 and it opens one window, I quit and open a folder from Finder in iTerm2 and it starts with that directory and only one window.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, it worked!